# A result set was generated for update spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

```
@Repository
public interface IReleaseHeaderDao extends CrudRepository<ReleaseHeader, Integer>{
    
}
```

In my Service:

```
    private void updatePfm(PushModel pushModel) {
       
       ReleaseHeader releaseHeader = this.releaseHeaderService.findById(162021);
       releaseHeader.setUpc(pushModel.getUpc());
       releaseHeaderService.save(releaseHeader);
    }
```

When I update in SQL server I received this result

[image]

But in spring when I saved the object to update it, I received this:
[image]

Comment: Show the code. An update statement, by itself, does not produce any resultset. Nor should it in most situations. Do you have a trigger on this table?

Comment: Yes, I have some triggers, what can I do in that case?

Comment: Develop good habits and follow best practices. A trigger should NOT produce a resultset since applications (and libraries) often do not expect them - as you see now. Remove the logic from the triggers that generates the resultsets.

Comment: Trigges were not deveped by me, but I already found the problems and yes, in fact are the triggers.

Comment: Could you please share more details of the solution as an answer? It would help other developers struggling with this error. Thanks.